# Having some issues with proxmox bridge on Hetzner

Tags: networking, bridge, proxmox, hetzner

So, i'm having 1 main IP and 1 addition IP that I've ordered for the server.

**Main IP:** xxx.xxx.200.200/27

**Additional IP:** xxx.xxx.202.175/27

This is my bridge configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.200.200/27
        gateway xxx.xxx.200.193
        broadcast xxx.xxx.200.223
        bridge-ports enp4s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        pointopoint xxx.xxx.200.193
        up ip route add xxx.xxx.202.175/27 dev vmbr0
```

And this is my node config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.202.175
        netmask xxx.xxx.255.224
        pointopoint xxx.xxx.200.200
        gateway xxx.xxx.200.200
```

The problem is that i can't even ping the IP of the node so i can't access to it through SSH.

Any ideas where i made a mistake?

Comment: `iface ens18 inet statuc` and `netmask xxx.xxx.225.224` are not correct. Most probably typo, it should be `iface ens18 inet static` `netmask xxx.xxx.255.224`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed

Comment: I advise you read those two Hetzner documentations first: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_Debian/en#Main_IP_Address , https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Zusaetzliche_IP-Adressen/en#Subnets . The main interface doesn't have to be part of the bridge. But the routing described there is quite atypical

Comment: Please take a look at the Hetzner Online Community, there is a quite good documentation about the Proxmox Virtual Environment and all the stuff that is needed to configure. https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-proxmox_ve